# Java Selenium Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication, IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I am just trying to run a basic webdriver program using the IntelliJ IDE but I get all these errors upon running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=59762:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\roone\IdeaProjects\WebDriverDemo\target\classes;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-java-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-chrome-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service-annotations\1.0\auto-service-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service\1.0\auto-service-1.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\auto-common\1.0\auto-common-1.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\30.1.1-jre\guava-30.1.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.8.0\checker-qual-3.8.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.5.1\error_prone_annotations-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chromium-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-chromium-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-http\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-http-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-json\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-json-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v85\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-v85-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v88\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-v88-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v89\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-v89-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v90\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-v90-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v91\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-devtools-v91-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-edge-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-firefox-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-ie-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-opera-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-remote-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.81\jcommander-1.81.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.63.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.63.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.63.Final\netty-codec-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.63.Final\netty-handler-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.63.Final\netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.63.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.63.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.63.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.63.Final\netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.63.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.63.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-api\1.2.0\opentelemetry-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-context\1.2.0\opentelemetry-context-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-exporter-logging\1.2.0\opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics\1.2.0-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.2.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-common\1.2.0\opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure\1.2.0-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.2.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-trace\1.2.0\opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-api-metrics\1.2.0-alpha\opentelemetry-api-metrics-1.2.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk\1.2.0\opentelemetry-sdk-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-semconv\1.2.0-alpha\opentelemetry-semconv-1.2.0-alpha.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\ous\jtoml\2.0.0\jtoml-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.11.0\byte-buddy-1.11.0.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client\2.12.3\async-http-client-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client-netty-utils\2.12.3\async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.60.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.60.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\netty\netty-reactive-streams\2.0.4\netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-safari-driver-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\4.0.0-beta-4\selenium-support-4.0.0-beta-4.jar;C:\Users\roone\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar com.pluralsight.WebDriverDemo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.pluralsight.WebDriverDemo.main(WebDriverDemo.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.HasAuthentication
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 19 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As I've read online or in other similar threads, it should be due to the lack of authentication of chrome. I tried different methods but none of them worked.
My WebDriverDemo.java file:

```
package com.pluralsight;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebDriverDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebDriverDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error might be related to the fact, that you do not have specified a chromedriver version. I would suggest using a driver manager. Add this dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then in your `WebDriverDemo.java` file you could initiate the webdriver like this:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("100.0.4896.60").setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

The versions might need updating, this code is copied from an older project of mine.

Also it might be an issue because you are using `http` instead of `https` in the link, I remember this causing issues as well.

Comment: I tried but it can't find the dependancy now. I receive the error "cannot find symbol variable WebDriverManager"

Comment: Have you just pasted the dependency to pom.xml? In that case, did you load Maven changes (Ctrl + Shift + O in IntelliJ)? Or you could install the dependency by using the Maven dependency manager (there is a tab at the bottom in IntelliJ called Dependencies)

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Any ideas how to remove the cookies window that pops up? Because of it my sendKeys method does not trigger and it causes the program to stop

Comment: You can’t remove the cookies window, you have to write an action which will click the button to accept the cookies or the button to close the cookies modal. You could try opening in incognito window and look if the cookies modal is present there.